# How to use inputs in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have this PHP file, which will write the text to a file:

```
<?php
$file = 'something.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new line to the file
$current .= "Some Text\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

But how do I make it so it takes the text from a input tag instead?
I am not very good at PHP, so sorry if it is obvious to you :(

Comment: Please clarify what "sends it" means here?

Comment: Okay, I edited it

Comment: Do you mean to append something you input from a text field (on web page) to a text file?

Comment: Yes, instead of how the code is atm

Comment: with PHP perferably

Comment: what is your exact requirement?you want to grab data from a file & put it in a textbox?

Comment: `$_POST` or `$_GET` then use the index you are sending and put it in the file. Also look at example 2, http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php, you dont need to build a string of the previous content, append.

Comment: Agree with @chris85 . Using append flag will be better when you just want to append something to that file, without modify previous contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html:

```
<form action="example.php">
    <input type="text" name="field">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['field'])) {
$file = 'something.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);

// Append a new line to the file
$current .= "\n".$_GET['field'];

// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
?>
```

or you can use the append flag mentioned in the previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a form in your webpage:

```
<form action="write.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="field">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in your "write.php" should have this:

```
<?php
    $file = 'something.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new line to the file
    $current .= $_POST["field"];
    $current .= "\n";
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Comment: The default method for a form is **GET**.

Comment: The default method for a form should be POST imo? GET is used to pass values directly from URL, e.g. http;//something/?field=xxx ; Edit: After checking @RaxWeber you're right, I've correct my answer.

Comment: Tell that to the standards committee.